# Compact SQL Remote Access

Tags: sql-server-ce, remote-access

I'm kind of newbie to the compact SQL edition and willing to use it in a new project which need to store local data but I would like to access to it from a remote computer also.
Is this possible? or is it meant only to be accessed from the local application ?

To be clear, I have an application running in computer A with a local DB file accessed with the embedded compact SQL in the app, and I need to access the data from computer B also.

Thanks in advance!
Nach

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server Compact Edition? There is a `sql-server-ce` tag for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For situations like that, you should use SQL Server (Express), or you must expose the data on computer A via a WCF Data Service (for example)